# What's the SQL Server equivalent for wait_timeout in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

In MySQL, we have `wait_timeout` server parameter which decides when to close the connection from the server side when it is idle. Is there a similar property for MSSQL (SQL Server) as well? If so, how do we configure that value? If not, are there any workarounds to achieve the same?

I couldn't find any configurations related to this in Azure portal as well.

Comment: Why do you want such a thing in either database? Having a long-lived connection is a **serious client bug**. Besides, with both servers connection pooling means those "idle" connections aren't wasted. When the client code closes the connection, it's actually reset and put in a connection pool for reuse. This way the client doesn't have to waste seconds opening new connections. The driver itself will close pooled connections that have been open for too long

Comment: Based on what property does the driver closes connection that have been open for too long? Is it `maxAge`? If the connection is closed from db server side using `wait_timeout`,  it will still be available in the pool and client can use it again after validation right?

Comment: The connection pool is maintained by the client, controlled by client-side settings. If the client goes down, the connections are closed. Again, why are you asking? Why do you want the *server* to close connections that it has no idea if they're used or not? And what would happen to the applications that tried to use those connections and found them closed? *What is the real problem you have?*

Comment: Typically though, the client-side pool timeout is [around 4-8 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#removing-connections). This allows the pool to grow if needed, eg due to high traffic then shrink again if traffic goes away. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) explain pooling in depth.

Comment: The main issue we have is that we see a thread stuck issue when the connections are validated before borrowing. We see this with both Azure MySQL and Azure SQL Server (different envs). We use a tomcat jdbc connection pool and we have confirmed that there are no connection leaks on our application (all are closed properly).

Comment: @RrR-, what exactly do you mean by thread stuck issues? I'm not very familiar with Tomcat but other JDBC connection poolers I've seen execute a health check query like `SELECT 1` periodically or prior to returning a pooled connection. If that's is hanging due to Java client thread issues, I don't see how that's related to db connections.

Comment: What does `a thread stuck issue` and `when the connections are validated before borrowing` mean? Where do you see that? Activity Monitor? Those aren't threads or processes, they are connections. You can inspect what that connection is running or *was* running. The connections you assume are closed may *not* be closed. If Tomcat enforces app level transactions, the database transaction **must** remain open until Tomcat either commits or rolls back the app transaction. That's the only way the DB transaction could be commit or roll back

Comment: So even in this case `wait_timeout` is the *wrong* solution. It will just cover up the actual problem and could cause more, eg if Tomcat tries to commit a transaction and there's no connection. You'd have to find *why* the business transaction froze, causing the connection to remain open

Comment: We see warnings from time to time from https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve.  I have attached part of the error stack in https://pastebin.com/eU6GrW76 . We see a similar stack with MySQL database as well. We have SELECT 1 as the validation query and `testOnBorrow=true` on pool as well.